# Using JSON.Simple with nested objects and arrays

Tags: java, json

I've decided on using JSON.Simple to parse Java in my application, as apposed to GSON or Jackson, because both of them seem over complicated for my needs and appeared to need additional class files to work as intended. I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "request":{
        "act":"rec_load_all",
        "email":"Redacted",
        "tkn":"Redacted",
        "a":"rec_load_all",
        "z":"Redacted"
    },
    "response":{
        "recs":{
            "has_more":false,
            "count":9,
            "objs":[{
                "rec_id":"1385442465",
                "rec_hash":"1825780e334bcd831034bd9ca62",
                "zone_name":"Redacted",
                "name":"Redacted",
                "display_name":"Redacted",
                "type":"A",
                "prio":null,
                "content":"Redacted",
                "display_content":"Redacted",
                "ttl":"1",
                "ttl_ceil":86400,
                "ssl_id":null,
                "ssl_status":null,
                "ssl_expires_on":null,
                "auto_ttl":1,
                "service_mode":"1",
                "props":{
                    "proxiable":1,
                    "cloud_on":1,
                    "cf_open":0,
                    "ssl":0,
                    "expired_ssl":0,
                    "expiring_ssl":0,
                    "pending_ssl":0,
                    "vanity_lock":0
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "result":"success",
    "msg":null
}
```

The `objs` array lists 9 different items, but I only included one for simplicity. I need to get `has_more`, `count`, and the `id` within `objs`. I've tried:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(responseString);
JSONArray objs = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("objs");
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = objs.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject idObj = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
    String id = (String) idObj.get("rec_id");
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

But it fires a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error, so I'm assuming because it's nested under `response -> recs -> objs` it isn't getting a value. I'm also following a few year old tutorial, so something could have changed since. If you could explain whats wrong and an example of how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it, I learn by seeing.

EDIT: Full error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ddns.Net.getId(Net.java:46)
    at ddns.DDNS.main(DDNS.java:7)
Java Result: 1
```

ddns.Net.getId(Net.java:46) | `Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = objs.iterator();`
ddns.DDNS.main(DDNS.java:7) | `Just calls the method`

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: @GaneshChithambalamA.S. Added it to the OP.

Comment: If it is throwing an NPE, then that means that `idObj` object might be null. It would be strange for `get` to throw NPE. It might return null but I wouldn't expect it to throw NPE.

Comment: I don't see id there in the JSON. Are you trying to get rec_id?

Comment: From the json you posted, the first object in the "objs" array doesnt seems to have "id"

Comment: @GaneshChithambalamA.S. Oops, simple mistake. Still didn't solve the problem and it's still giving the same error. I updated the OP to include `rec_id` instead of `id` also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to take any json object from parent and so on, take a look this code (I tried and works):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("json.json");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    JSONObject result = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
    JSONObject response = (JSONObject) result.get("response");
    JSONObject recs = (JSONObject) response.get("recs");

    boolean hasMore = (Boolean) recs.get("has_more");
    JSONArray objs = (JSONArray) recs.get("objs");
    System.out.println(recs);
    System.out.println("has more " + hasMore);

    Iterator objIter = objs.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (objIter.hasNext()) {
        i++;
        System.out.println(String.format("obj %d: %s", i, objIter.next()));
    }

}
```

There is another way that for me is easier and is to create a Java Bean with the same structure so... you will parse a hole object, if you are interested on this approach let me know.

Comment: For learning purposes, if you'd like to provide both approaches that would be great.

Comment: I'm having an issue with your code. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
 at ddns.Net.getId(Net.java:46)
 at ddns.DDNS.main(DDNS.java:7)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: My example reads from a local file called json.json, for your test use your parser instead of mine. So... copy my code from line JSONObject result = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);, but instead of (reader) put (inputString).

Comment: To parse an object you could use Jackson so you could forget about parsing manually.

Comment: Wow, sorry about that. I completely ignored the first few lines assuming they were the same. It appears to be working now. I took a look at Jackson but it seemed too complicated. If you want to provide and example with that, then go ahead. I don't expect you to code the program for me though.

Comment: I used Jackson with String MVC and is really easy a nice, check this tutorial is pretty good and I think it fits your needs: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Answer (score 0):

@Carlos Verdes pointed me in the right direction.

From the larger JSON I want put the name of the league, `My_League`, in a string because its different for each user.

JSON Snippet shortened for brevity:

```
{..."name":"Some_Dude", ... ,"expLevel":221,"league":{"id":12345,"name":"My_League","iconUrls":...},...}
```

Multiple occurrences of the key `"name"` exist in the JSON and if you look for key `"name"` again JSON.Simple just retrieves the first occurrence of `"name"` which would be `"Some_Dude"` thats right at the beginning.

So to get around that I set that section of the JSON, key `"league"`, into a JSON object and then extracted key `"name"` from the object to get `"My_League"` for my string.

```
JSONObject leagueObj = (JSONObject) each.get("league");
String league = (String)leagueObj.get("name");
```

The key take away is that when you extract `"league":` you will get everything after `:` including all things between `{..}` up to the next `,` that is outside the closing curly `}`.  Which, in my case, is more than you need leaving you to have parse that smaller section, hence the JSON Object.